# Snowflake ODBC setup for AzureAD authentication for MicroStrategy Server

Tags: azure-active-directory, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, microstrategy

We're using MicroStrategy on-premises to access a warehouse in Snowflake. All the users connecting to Snowflake are authenticated through Azure AD. We want the same for MicroStrategy instead of using a local Snowflake account.

Is that possible?

Right now, when a user wants to connect through ODBC, we set up the Authenticator = ExternalBrowser. So when they use any software, the browser pops up for the authentication and then they continue to do their thing.

How can I set the ODBC of the MicroStrategy server to use the Azure AD authentication, without using the browser and by specifying the username we created for MicroStrategy in our AD.

Thanks,

JFS.

Answer (score 1):

This likely requires you to configure MicroStrategy, Snowflake, and Azure AD to leverage OAuth2.

MicroStrategy has a how to guide here:

https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/current/Gateway_Connections/WebHelp/Lang_1033/Content/integrate_sso_using_azure_for_snowflake.htm